# AJAX request - cookie authentication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox, firefox-addon

I am building a little widget (using JavaScript) which needs to interact with a RoR web application via AJAX. The workflow for a user looks like this:

1. Login to the RoR web app
2. Get browser extension or bookmarklet (both share the same codebase), whichever
3. Go to a website and activate the widget
4. Point stuff on that website you want to get saved, press ok
5. You get back a URL on the web app with the captured content

The workflow in the widget code looks something like:

1. Collect stuff from the DOM and issue a relevant jQuery JSONP request
2. If there's a custom status message in the response reading 'unauthorized', open an `<iframe />` with an authorization page originating from the web app — if auth is successful in the response there's a `Set-Cookie` header setting the auth cookie needed for subsequent AJAX requets
3. If there's been auth needed, try the JSONP request again

This just works for the bookmarklet. However, for a Firefox extension, the web app receives the requests stripped of the auth cookie. Stripped of all cookies in fact. Seems like the requests are sandboxed.
Now I know there's `@mozilla.org/cookieService` available for extensions. Questions are:

1. how would I pass a cookie from the extension's main.js to a JSONP request in a content script?
2. how would I get the cookie for the development env, with url localhost:3000? The `cookieService` returns null as cookies for that url
3. is it feasible to change the way authentication is resolved, from cookies to something else?

Answer (score 0):

The requests are not really sandboxed, but lack an origin document. Because of that the network code does not know if the request is a *first party* or *third party* request, and will by default treat it as the latter. Firefox disabled sending cookies to third party servers a while ago, and that is why there are no cookies in your requests.

In a XUL/XPCOM add-on you'd do (easiest way):

```
var req = <construct xmlhttprequest>;
...
req.open(...);
if (req.channel instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannelInternal) {
  req.channel.forceAllowThirdPartyCookie = true;
}
```

Add-on SDK users would can do the following when using `net/xhr`:

```
const { XMLHttpRequest, forceAllowThirdPartyCookie } = require("sdk/net/xhr");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
req.open(...);
forceAllowThirdPartyCookie(req);
```

The higher-level `request` module always calls `forceAllowThirdPartyCookie` automatically.

Now back to your questions:

1. Do not use `JSONP`. That is basically the same as `eval()`ing remote, untrusted code in a (somewhat) secure context. You never know if there are man-in-the-middle attackers around (if using insecure connections) or if the server got compromised (all connections).

   Anyway, content-scripts cannot use the above methods, so you'd have to do the request in privileged code (e.g. `main.js`) and use message passing to pass the response over to the content script.
2. You really shouldn't use `nsICookieService*` directly. If you really like to use the service, then read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=nsicookieservice).
3. You can always switch to another auth scheme I guess. Which one to use and how to do it would depend on your requirements (i.e. too broad to answer).